# I'm using python 2.7. i tried all ways to setup the xlrd file, but still i'm getting the error: ImportError: No module named xlrd >>>

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import xlrd
from lxml import etree
```

I'm using python 2.7. i tried all ways to setup the xlrd file, but still i'm getting the error:

> ImportError: No module named xlrd >>>

Also i'm unable to run pip from cmd prompt, though pip is installed.

Comment: "Unable to run pip"  - why? What happens when you try?

Comment: it says "Did not provide a command"

Comment: C:\Users\ABC>get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390
b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
Successfully installed pip-10.0.1

Comment: But still not able to access xlrd